# Display component with checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to know if ,it's possible to display a component on clicking a checkbox.
I make a dashboard and I need to select the tools that I want to see in my screen.

I have made checkbox with v-model="select", value="name of component"
and next a list rendering with v-for, but it only display the value, not the component.

In the fiddle , I want to display different tools, but nothing happen.
I want display a name in select menu different of the component name.
https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianczech/2wfapuv4/85/

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="app">
<v-app >
<v-select
    v-model="selectedTools"
    :items="tools"
    label="Select"
    multiple
></v-select>


 </v-app>
</div>
```

```
Vue.component('comp_hammer', {
    template: `<span>Tool 1</span>`
});

Vue.component('comp_screw', {
    template: `<span>Tool 2</span>`
});

Vue.component('comp_drill', {
    template: `<span>Tool 3</span>`
});

Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {


  },
  data() {
    return {
        tools:['tool 1', 'tool 2', 'tool 3'],
        selectedTools: [],
     }
   }
})
```

Comment: Look up use of dynamic components - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using dynamic components: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

I've edited your fiddle to suit your use-case, check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/z8v1pq5j/

To show a different text from the component name, the items you use should be objects with the `text` (label) and `value` properties.

Comment: the dynamic component looks great , but How apply in my case with checkbox? some help please

Comment: it is pssible to have the same v-model, because I have a lots of component and I don't want to have several v-model, just one with array will be nice.

Comment: I how can use it with select multiple, can you show me in your fiddle ?

Comment: I'll test it in some minutes

Comment: that doesn't work form me like this, I've update my post

Comment: @Sébastian I've updated the answer with some changes to your own fiddle. Check it out

Comment: @Sébastian I just pasted the wrong link, try it now

Comment: Just a last question, how can I do for having all the component display at beginning

Comment: @Sébastian just initialize your array of selected items with all the components in it

Comment: @Sébastian in the data of your instance you declare `selectedTools` like this: `selectedTools: ['comp_hammer', 'comp_screw', 'comp_drill']`